# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)' occuring randomly while processing in the loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large workbook containing about 40 sheets, over 20 VBA functions (that is why I don't want to post all the code) and 20 MB of data. The goal of whole mechanism is to create every week about 200 reports, based on current data, and then export every to separate PDF. Everything works in one, big loop, so reports are creating one by one. Algorithm copy empty worksheets with template, put values, formats and plots inside, then export these sheets into PDF and delete them, so the problem is not about memory overflow (I suppose).

So, the error occurs randomly on some iteration of this big loop. Sometimes on 20th iteration, sometimes on 50th (for the same input data). It stops on some point and show this message:

[image]

When I click on Debug button it gives this:

[image]

When I click on Debug button second time, it gives:

[image]

and Excel shout down, so I don't have an opportunity to debug it. I know that this last message is in Polish (because of system language which I can't change) but it says that Microsoft Excel stopped working and Windows can try to reopen it.

I tried to change every `.Merge` function to something else, but then error occurs on some `.Copy` function. As far as I could research, a Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)' is very generic error, which don't help at all.

Did anyone have similar issue? Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

On request of @mo.h I post the code where the error occurs. It's just a part of the algorithm, so I don't know if this would be helpful.

```
Sub KRS2doArkusza(Spolka As String, KDSstr As String, KRSstr As String)
Dim strona As Integer
Dim lElementow As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
    strona = 2
    lSekcji = 2

    Dim ZakrDane As Range
    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    Range("B2").Value = Spolka
    Range("B3").Value = KDSstr
    Range("B4").Value = KRSstr

    ' Wyk 2
    Dim lKol As Integer
    HistSkumKRSDoSklep

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    Range(Range("H23:H24"), Range("H23:H24").End(xlToRight)).Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    Range("B41").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Range("B41").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    lKol = Selection.Columns.Count

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    Range(Range("H25"), Range("H25").End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    Range("B43").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Range("B43").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    For i = 2 To lKol + 1
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, i), Cells(42, i))
        Rng.Merge
    Next i

    Range(Range("B40:B42"), Range("B40:B42").End(xlToRight)).Select
    obramowanie

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Range(Range("B43"), Range("B43").End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    obramowanie

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wykres 3").Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    Range("C63").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Wyk 2"

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 2").Height = ActiveSheet.Range("F63:F102").Height
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 2").Width = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:N1").Width

    ' Wyk 1
    Hist_KRS

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    Range(Range("D1:F1"), Range("D1:F1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select

    Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    Range(Range("E1"), Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    Range("D15").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    Range("B14:B15").Merge
    Range("C14:C15").Merge
    Range("D14:D15").Merge

    Range("B14:D15").Select
    obramowanie

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Range(Range("B16:D16"), Range("B16:D16").End(xlDown)).Select
    obramowanie

    Sheets("Raport Hist").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wykres 2").Copy
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    Range("F14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Wyk 1"

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 1").Height = ActiveSheet.Range("F14:F33").Height
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 1").Width = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:O1").Width

    ' Tytuły
    Sheets("Output" & strona).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 1").Select
    Range("B11").Value = ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Delete

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Wyk 2").Select
    Range("B37").Value = ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried it in batches of 10 say?  see if there is a particular type of cell(s) that's causing the error.  Have you done the usual calcs off etc.?

Comment: Can you try to post the code section that contaisn the range merge? give us something to work with :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, I tried to put them in batches. The result is the same: sometimes everything is fine, sometimes error occurs on like 6th or 8th iteration. Yes, I can see which operation on which cells causing the problem, but when I change or even erase this function, error occurs on the other. Basically, at some point, every function connected with `Range().` property (like `.Copy`, `.PasteSpecial`, `.Merge`, `.Delete`) becomes corrupted. I can't make just `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, because there are some Excel formulas that I want to calculate while processing.

Comment: You can calculate before hand and at certain points, controlling it, for example, my work involved 90+ sheets, copying pasting this that and the other, froze loads.  Removing things like copy and paste, and changing to `worksheets(destination).range("a1").value=worksheets(origin).range("a1").value` and then `worksheets(destination).calculate` for example improved performance.  You could be just doing too much.

Comment: Without the actual code we can do nothing but guess (as Nathan_Sav) is currently doing. My personal guess (from these three lines of code you gave us in a screenshot) is that your macro is poorly programmed which leads essentially to a variable or object being reassigned before releasing it (similar to a stack overflow) or that your code is not fully qualified and thus tries to alter an unintended sheet like this: (1) program runs, (2) you get bored, (3) you click some place, (4) the active sheet gets changed and unqualified code such as the above refers to the unwanted / (now) active sheet.

Comment: @Ralph I am not clicking anywhere while macro is processing ;) . About this "variable or object being reassigned before releasing it", have you got some hint or article about how to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, I did notice no book/sheet prefixes to the range's, so functioning on activeworkbook and activesheet

Comment: @mo.h I have uploaded this code.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ok, so I try to reactor It to not use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Raport Hist the work on this sheet for example, can be done via an array, and the same concept in my comment, also you paste all, then values.  range(x).value=range(x).value can be more efficient than paste values.  Also this `Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, i), Cells(42, i))` can be `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(40, i), Cells(42, lcol)).merge` no need for loop

Comment: There is also an across flag on the merge, so `Range("A1:B28").Merge True` can be done.  Avoid using select, use `dim wbOrigin as Excel.worksheet` and then `set wbOrigin=thisworkbook.worksheets("Raport Hist")` then `wbOrigin.range(xyz).......`

Comment: Thanks for uploading the code. This may be too simple but can you tell us what is actually in cells B14 and B15 please?

Comment: @mo.h B15 contains some value and B14 is empty. As I mentioned, I tryed to erase all the `.Merge` functions, but the problem just occurs in different place.

Comment: @Limak have you tried putting it in a with block? i tested this simple line in excel and it manages to merge just fine. I am sticking to basics here as your issue may be something small :)

Comment: @mo.h you mean like putting it into 3 different lines, like `With Range("B14:B15")` <next line> `.Merge` <next line> `End With`, right?

Comment: no but see answer below...